# MS Graph API Error: 'Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadsS2SRequest

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm getting the following error message.

```
Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadsS2SRequest
```

when trying to `Add`, `Update` or `Delete` channels using `MS Graph API` for Teams. The calls were working fine for a while but now suddenly this error comes up. This happens particularly when the channel type is `private`. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a temporary system error. I tried adding, updating, deleting channels and it's working for me. If you still can repro the issue, then share the Graph API call that you're calling and the response logs(contains the requestid, timestamp) for analysis. In addition, try to make the call from Microsoft Graph explorer as well

Comment: @ Hi Zion, Did the above comment by Dev fixed your issue?

Comment: @Manish-MSFT This has been a serious issue and MS hasn't done anything. This is breaking our production apps. Please take it up with the Eng team and get a fix soon. The unreliable way Graph API works makes life extremely hard.

Comment: @Zion, could you please post endpoint URL and Request.

Comment: @Manish-MSFT This seems to be working now. Hope it will continue...