# Unable to create Private teams via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am unable to create **Private** teams via Graph API even though the visibility is set to "Private". It just keeps churning out "Public" teams. This was working fine until a few days ago.

Comment: Could you please share the MS Graph call that you are using?

Comment: Hi @Shiva-MSFTIdentity  The request look lilke...

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams

    "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
    "visibility": "Private",
    "displayName": "Class 1",
    "description": "ClassID",

There is also a problem with Add, Update and Remove channels. 
    Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadsS2SRequest
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858194/ms-graph-api-error-failed-to-execute-skype-backend-request-getthreadss2sreques/64893284#64893284

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/team?view=graph-rest-beta) every team is associated with a group. So create a group with visibility as private by following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-create-group-and-team). Your team will become private.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity The method you had said is a 2 step process. First to create Group and then to make it Teams enabled. The method I used is a single step process where you directly create a Group and make it a Team. This process worked perfectly well before. It's just last few days that all these problems have come up. So please try to replicated the problem in your side. Thanks

Comment: I was also able to reproduce your issue with this single call. As a work around you can try the 2 steps process as said above.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity It's not that easy as, this means changing production code. Secondly, the 2 step process works differently and we can do it by using a custom connector for the power platfom. Even further, this is such a serious issue which can cause Data Protection issues. So kindly take it up with the Eng team immediately. Thanks.

Comment: We are able to reproduced the Issue and raised a bug.

Comment: @VaraPrasad-MSFT As this is a very serious issue, could you please escalate it for a quick fix. Thanks.

Comment: @VaraPrasad-MSFT Has this been fixed?

Comment: @Zion : we have raised a bug and we don't have any ETA to share.

Comment: As of 31-01-2023, still not working via teams endpoint.